# How can I input array items with a variable? (php)

Tags: php

If I want to create an array:

```
$tem='12,13,14,15';

$arr = array($tem); //which is wrong
```

Instead of:

```
$arr = array(12,13,14,15);
```

How can I do? There's always a syntax error.

Comment: Hi, you can't add multiple entries in that way. Try exploding your string and then running through the resulting array with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do it, anyway:

```
$tem='12,13,14,15';

$arr = explode(',', $tem);
```